# Why do I get "Failed to load resource" when I mount the component in Vue.js?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have two errors in my Vue components due to when I mount the component. The console log report shows me these 404 errors

> 1)[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)  localhot8000/movies/getComments
>
> 2)[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)  localhot8000/movies/comment/store

It cannot find my function, but I've look my code and I don't know how to fix this error.

Follow the code of my route on `web.php:`

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');

Route::resource('movies', App\Http\Controllers\MovieController::class); 

Route::post('/comment/store','CommentController@store');
Route::get('/getComments/{movie}','CommentController@getComments');
```

Follow my code of my `show.blade.php`

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

    <div class="container my-2">

        <div class="card mb-3">
          <img src="{{ asset('images/movies/' . $movie->image) }}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">{{$movie->title}}</h5>
            <p class="card-text"> {{$movie->description}}</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">{{$movie->actor}}</small></p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">{{$movie->gender}}</small></p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted"> {{$movie->duration}}</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>

          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <comment-component :userid="{{Auth::user()->id}}" :movieid="{{$movie->id}}"></comment-component>
            <get-comments-component :userid="{{Auth::user()->id}}" :movieid="{{$movie->id}}"></get-comments-component>
          </div>
        </div>
      
        
        <span></span>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning"><a href="{{route("movies.index")}}"class="btn btn primary">Back to Movies</a></button>
      
      </tr>
    </div>
</thead>

@endsection
```

Follow my code of my `CommentComponent.vue`

```
<template>
 <div class="card text-center">
          <div class="card-header">
            Comments
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Nome user</h5>

           <textarea name="comment" :v-model="formData.comment" class="form-control mb-1" rows="2" placeholder="Write a comment here..."   ></textarea>
            <button class="btn btn-success float-right" @click="commentStore">Add Comment</button>
            
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer text-muted">
            2 days ago
          </div>
        </div>

</template>

<script>
    export default {
     props:['userid','movieid'],
     data(){
       return{
         formData:{
           comment:'',
              user_id:this.userid,
                movie_id:this.movieid
             }
       }
    },
    methods:{
        commentStore(){
            axios.post('comment/store',this.formData).then((response)=>{
                console.log(response.data)
                this.formData.comment=''
                }).catch((error)=>{
                    console.log(error)
                });
        }
    }
    }

</script>
```

Follow my code of my `GetCommentsComponent.vue`

```
<template>
 <div class="card text-center">
          <div class="card-header">
            Comments
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Nome user</h5>
            <p v-for="(comment,index) in comments" :key="index">
            <span class="badge badge-pill badge-light">{{ comment.user.name }} Commented: </span> {{ comment.comment }}
            </p> 
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer text-muted">
            2 days ago
          </div>
        </div>

</template>

<script>
    export default {
     props:['userid','movieid'],
     data(){
        return{
            comments:{}
        }
     },
     mounted(){
        this.getComments()
        this.interval=setInterval(function(){
            this.getComments()
        }.bind(this),500)
     },
     methods:{
        getComments(){
            axios.get('getComments/'+this.movieid).then((response)=>{
                this.comments = response.data
            }).catch((errors)=>{
                console.log(errors)
            });
        }
     }
    }
</script>
```

Follow my cod of my `App.js`

```
/**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */

require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue').default;

/**
 * The following block of code may be used to automatically register your
 * Vue components. It will recursively scan this directory for the Vue
 * components and automatically register them with their "basename".
 *
 * Eg. ./components/ExampleComponent.vue -> <example-component></example-component>
 */

// const files = require.context('./', true, /\.vue$/i)
// files.keys().map(key => Vue.component(key.split('/').pop().split('.')[0], files(key).default))

Vue.component('comment-component', require('./components/CommentComponent.vue').default);
Vue.component('get-comments-component', require('./components/GetCommentsComponent.vue').default);

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

Follow my code of my `Commentcontroller`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Models\Movie;
use App\Models\Comment;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CommentController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
    //$request->all();
    $comment = new Comment;
    $comment->insert([
        'movie_id' => $request->movie_id,
        'user_id' => $request->user_id,
        'comment' => $request->comment,

    ]);

    return response()->json($comment);
}

    public function getComments(Movie $movie)
    {
        return response()->json($movie->comments()->with('user')->latest()->get());
    }
}
```

Code for my Eloquent models:

#### User

```php
 public function movies()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Movie');
    }

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }
```

#### Movie

```php
 public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function comments(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }
}
```

#### Comment

```php
 public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function movie(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Movie');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue isn't being caused by Vue failing to mount the components. The HTTP 404 errors are due to your `axios()` calls trying to load incorrect URLs. You're using relative URLs which will be affected by the current page URL.

If we look at your routes, we have these two entries:

```php
Route::post('/comment/store','CommentController@store');
Route::get('/getComments/{movie}','CommentController@getComments');
```

Which create the following URLs:

```
localhot:8000/comment/store
localhot:8000/getComments/{movie}
```

You can use `php artisan route:list` to see a list of the URLs available in your Laravel app.

When we look at the two Vue components that reference these URLs, you'll see the following:

```js
axios.get('getComments/'+this.movieid).then((response)=>{ ...
axios.post('comment/store',this.formData).then((response)=>{ ...
```

You're using a `route::resource('movies')` [Resource Controller](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#actions-handled-by-resource-controller), so your `show()` method will have the URL of `localhot:8000/movies/{id}`.

This means you're Ajax calls are expecting URLs of:

```
localhot:8000/movies/comment/store
localhot:8000/movies/getComments/{movie}
```

which leads to the HTTP 404 errors.

The fix should be a quick one: your just need to update your Axios calls to ensure they're referring the correct URLs:

```js
axios.get('/getComments/'+this.movieid).then((response)=>{ ...
           ^ added forward slash to get correct URL
axios.post('/comment/store',this.formData).then((response)=>{ ...
            ^ added
```